# How to use call_user_func() instead of eval()?

Tags: php, eval

I needed to automatically get parameters from a `$_GET['url']` variable. So I thought I'll make it using `eval()` function.

As I've heard how not-secure it is, I began to search for another solution and I've found a function called `call_user_func()`, but I really don't know how to use it.

This is the code, which worked correctly, but I don't want use it anymore. Can you tell me how to make it working with `call_user_func()`?

```
$execute = '$controller->' . "$url[1](";

for($i=2; $i<count($url); $i++){
    $execute .= "'" . $url[$i] . "'";
    if($i<count($url)-1){
        $execute .= ", ";
    }
}

$execute .= ');';
eval($execute);
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is this ? Anyways, check [call-user-func](http://bd1.php.net/function.call-user-func) here.

Comment: you dont need eval. `$controller->{$url[1]}();`

Comment: I wanted to be able to call parameters automaticlly. For example 127.0.0.1/cms/controller/method/param1/param2/param3... I was trying to make simple for or foreach loop, but it just didn't work. It was always an issue with syntax, because I couldn't separate the parameters. And I've found the solution with eval() on internet, but it's not secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead:

```
if (method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
    call_user_func_array(array($controller, $url[1]), array_splice($url, -2));    
}
```

Basically check if the method exists, if so call it with the list of arguments. This will be basically doing:

```
$controller->{$url[1]}($url[2], $url[3], $url[4], ..);
```

[call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) is ideal if you have no parameters to call, or if the parameters you want to call are in 1 array variable, something like `function test (array $arguments)`.

Comment: OK, I'll do how you are saying. If there is no way to do it automaticlly, I'll work with the second solution. Thanks.